# Retrieve single field using CAML Query in Sharepoint using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, caml-query, caml

I have a List called ProjectInformation and contains following Fields..

```
ID  ProjectName1  ProjectManager   ProjectExecution

1     EDS           PPB              Time and Material
2     CS            PQR              Fixed Price
```

I want to retrieve single field as we can do in SQL as :

```
Select ProjectExecution from ProjectInformation where ProjectName1 ='EDS'
```

How in CAML Query..??

**My Code **

```
function rtsample(){
    document.getElementById("tbl").style.visibility="hidden";
    var cc = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var alllist = cc.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ProjectInformation');
    var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
    caml.set_viewXml('<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="ProjectExecution"/>ViewFields</View>');
    this.list = alllist.getItems(caml);
    cc.load(list,'Include(ProjectExecution)');
cc.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.QuerySucceeded5),Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
    }
    function QuerySucceeded5(){
    var listiteminfo='';

    var listItemEnumerator = list.getEnumerator();
    while(listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
      var listitem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

     listiteminfo += '\nID:'+ listitem.get_id();
                     alert(listiteminfo.toString());     
    }
    alert(listiteminfo.toString());
    }
    function onQueryFailed(){
    alert("Failed");
    }
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: You have caml.set_viewXmll , should be caml.set_viewXml . '<ViewFields>' is not closed with </viewFields>, same with 'View>' </View>

Answer (score 2):

The below code will help you

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ProjectInformation");
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where>--your query goes here --   </Where></Query></View>');
var collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem, 'Include(ProjectExecution)');
context.executeQueryAsync(function () { successCallback() }, function (sender, args) { failureCallback() });
```

The `Include` in `context.load()` is used to fetch only required fields.

P.S. There is also a `<ViewField>` tag in CAML query which can be used but it also fetches the mandatory columns like `Created`, `Created By` etc., so I would recommend to use `Include`

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185009(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection1)

Comment: i want only CAML query which i have done in SQL...Rest of the things i know..

Comment: Use this camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="ProjectExecution"/></ViewFields></View>');

Comment: I wish I know the reason behind a downvote.

Comment: Plz, check my code above...still its not working

Comment: What is the error you are getting? You wont get ID column value as it is not included in Include statement. Use Include(ProjectExecution, ID). This is in addition to Anders comment above

Answer (score 0):

Because someone already answered to your question, I'll suggest another solution.
If you don't mind to use a thrid party library, you can look at my [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) library. With it you don't need to write the CAML Query but you use a SQL-like syntax for the WHERE clause.

In your case, all the above code will look like this:

```
$SP().list("ProjectInformation").get({
  fields:"ID,ProjectExecution",
  where:"ProjectName1 = 'EDS'",
  orderby:"ProjectExecution ASC"
}, function(data) {
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].getAttribute("ID"), data[i].getAttribute("ProjectExecution"));
  }
})
```